# How to set tkinter scale slider's color?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, scale

I want set slider color(arrow part), I try many parameter only `-background` can changed slider's color.

[image]

But slider and background will changed color together when I used `-background`, like this:

[image]

If I set color same with background color, It caused hard to find slider.

How to just set slider's color?

My scale code:

```
s2 = Scale(control_frame, from_=0, to=100, tickinterval=100, sliderrelief='flat', orient="horizontal", highlightthickness=0, background='black', fg='grey', troughcolor='#73B5FA', activebackground='#1065BF')
s2.place(x=70, y=600, anchor='nw', width = 280, height = 50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, we have to use a ttk style, so we need to use a `ttk.Scale`, however, it does not accept all the options of the `tk.Scale` you are using. Therefore, I suggest you to use the `TickScale` from the [ttkwidgets](https://pypi.org/project/ttkwidgets) module (See documentation [here](https://ttkwidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ttkwidgets/ttkwidgets/ttkwidgets.TickScale.html#ttkwidgets.TickScale)). This way you can combine the `tk.Scale` options with the ttk styling.

The idea is to:

1. create images of the desired color for the slider, e.g. with
   `tk.PhotoImage`:

   ```
   img_slider = tk.PhotoImage(width=30, height=15)
   img_slider.put("{<pixel_color> ... <pixel_color>} {<second line>} ...")
   ```

   I used a basic rectangle, but you can also load a more elaborated image if you wish.
2. create the colored slider theme element:

   ```
   style.element_create('custom.Horizontal.Scale.slider', 'image', img_slider,
                        ('active', img_slider_active))
   ```

   I also used a different image `img_slider_active`, to highlight the slider when the cursor is on it.
3. Use the new element in a custom style

   ```
   style.layout('custom.Horizontal.TScale',
                [('Horizontal.Scale.trough',
                  {'sticky': 'nswe',
                   'children': [('custom.Horizontal.Scale.slider',
                                 {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''})]})])
   ```
4. Apply the custom style to your `TickScale` widget. Since the `TickScale` is based on a `ttk.Scale`, you need to use the style to set the background, foreground and troughcolor options, see full code below.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkwidgets import TickScale

def set_img_color(img, color):
    """Change color of PhotoImage img."""
    pixel_line = "{" + " ".join(color for i in range(img.width())) + "}"
    pixels = " ".join(pixel_line for i in range(img.height()))
    img.put(pixels)

root = tk.Tk()
# create images used for the theme
slider_width = 30
slider_height = 15
# normal slider
img_slider = tk.PhotoImage('img_slider', width=slider_width, height=slider_height, master=root)
set_img_color(img_slider, "red")
# active slider
img_slider_active = tk.PhotoImage('img_slider_active', width=slider_width, height=slider_height, master=root)
set_img_color(img_slider_active, '#1065BF')

style = ttk.Style(root)
style.theme_use('clam')
# create scale element
style.element_create('custom.Horizontal.Scale.slider', 'image', img_slider,
                     ('active', img_slider_active))
# create custom layout
style.layout('custom.Horizontal.TScale',
             [('Horizontal.Scale.trough',
               {'sticky': 'nswe',
                'children': [('custom.Horizontal.Scale.slider',
                              {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''})]})])
style.configure('custom.Horizontal.TScale', background='black', foreground='grey',
                troughcolor='#73B5FA')
scale = TickScale(root, from_=0, to=100, tickinterval=100, orient="horizontal",
                  style='custom.Horizontal.TScale')
scale.pack(fill='x')
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
slider.configure(foreground=color)
```

draws a rectangle around the slider, which distinguishes it from the trough. Setting the foreground color the same as the background color creates a difficult to find slider, as you stated.

Another option is to use a different theme (https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html). The snippet below allows you to see how your slider would look with different themes:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # root window
        self.title('Theme Demo')
        self.geometry('400x300')
        self.style = ttk.Style(self)

        # label
        label = ttk.Label(self, text='Name:')
        label.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10,  sticky='w')
        # scale
        slider = ttk.Scale(self, from_=1, to=10)
        slider.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=10, pady=10,  sticky='w')
        # button
        btn = ttk.Button(self, text='Show')
        btn.grid(column=2, row=0, padx=10, pady=10,  sticky='w')

        # radio button
        self.selected_theme = tk.StringVar()
        theme_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text='Themes')
        theme_frame.grid(padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=20, ipady=20, sticky='w')


        for theme_name in self.style.theme_names():
            rb = ttk.Radiobutton(
                theme_frame,
                text=theme_name,
                value=theme_name,
                variable=self.selected_theme,
                command=self.change_theme)
            rb.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

    def change_theme(self):
        self.style.theme_use(self.selected_theme.get())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```