# Can't change background of ttk Scale

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, background, slider

I have a very simple program:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# Create a new style with a red background for the slider
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('Custom.Horizontal.TScale', background='red')

# Create a new window with a slider widget using the custom style
root = tk.Tk()
slider = ttk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=100, length=200, orient='horizontal', style='Custom.Horizontal.TScale')
slider.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

But the background of the slider remains unchanged.
I've already looked at this question: [How to set tkinter scale slider's color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59642558/how-to-set-tkinter-scale-sliders-color)

And it didn't work for me. The docs say you need to use a style, so I have. I also tried changing the troughcolor but that didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the background of the slider remains unchanged

You cannot put `root=tk.Tk()` after `style = ttk.Style()`

Move `root=tk.Tk()` before `style = ttk.Style()`

snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

# Create a new style with a red background for the slider
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('Custom.Horizontal.TScale', background='red')

# Create a new window with a slider widget using the custom style
 
slider = ttk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=100, length=200, orient='horizontal', style='Custom.Horizontal.TScale')
slider.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this really helped. I actually encountered this problem whilst trying to set up an example for an issue I was having - if i use a custom theme, e.g. put sv_ttk.set_theme("dark") after the window initialisation, the bg doesn't change. How could I fix that?

Comment: Do you know how I could fix this other issue? I think it's because the theme uses an image for the scale element so may be unsolveable but it's strange no-one else has had this issue.